# how to prevent image from moving down when screen size changed

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

i've this code
of two images in the two sides of the screen

```
<p>
    <img class= "imgright" alt="מתן לוי טיפול בכעס" src="images/treatment-of-anger.jpg" />
    <a href ="http://www.anger.co.il">
         <img class= "imgleft" alt="מתן לוי טיפול בכעס" src="images/Bkalut-treatment-of-anger.png" />
    </a>
</p>
<p>
```

Then I have two images and a text in the center of the screen - between the two images above

```
<p>
    <h1>
         <a><img class="img1" src="images/anger.gif" alt="כעס"        style="float:center" > </a>
         כעס!!!
         <a><img class="img1" src="images/anger.gif" alt="כעס"> </a>
    </h1>
</p>
<p>
    <ul>
```

this is the css
    .row.block01 img1
    {
      float:center ; 
      align:center
    }

```
.imgright
{
  float:right;
  width:62px;
  height:112px;
  padding:5px;

  margin: 5px 20px 5px 0px;
}

.imgleft
{
  float:left;
  width:102px;
  height:112px;
  padding:5px;

  margin: 5px 20px 5px 0px;
}
```

the problem is that when the width of the screen becomes smaller the two images  in the middle become one above the text and one below the text only whe the screen become more small all the text move down and the two images is again in it's two sides.

Comment: Are you trying to create a responsive website either a non-responsive.

Comment: Can your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) your code

Comment: i fiddle my code here http://jsfiddle.net/bfmqf2fn/

Answer (score 0):

You could force the p tag to maintain a min-width, which would stop the images from restacking, but you haven't posted what your desired functionality is.

Try this in your css:

```
p {
    min-width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: How big are all the images?

Comment: ypu can see the problem in this fidle it's not mattar what the picture size is  see this filddle the problem http://jsfiddle.net/bfmqf2fn/

Comment: i may didn't explain myself enough. i need the two inner images in the two sides of the DVD!!! text and not one above the text and one below it

Comment: Sorry, didn't update before I posted the last one, how about this http://jsfiddle.net/nzy6pr35/2/

Answer (score 0):

There is no float: center.  You can center the element by using the code:

> .center {
>       margin-left: auto;
>       margin-right: auto;
>       width: 70%;
>       background-color: #b0e0e6;
>   }
>   .

Set both margin-left and margin-right to auto like above.  You can find more examples at [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com). That code could be causing your error.  You should also enclose the p tag in a div, then set a min-width for the div.  This will help with your organization later on.

Comment: i didn't understand when to put the center element